# Remove unused referenced assemblies in a xaml file

Tags: c#, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

When I open my windows workflow file(.xaml) in code view I see this huge list of referenced assemblies

```
<TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="AssemblyReference">
      <AssemblyReference>Antlr3.Runtime</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>AutoMapper</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>dk.nita.saml20</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>DocumentFormat.OpenXml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>EntityFramework</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>EntityFramework.Extended</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>EntityFramework.SqlServer</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>log4net</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.CSharp</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Newtonsoft.Json</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Ninject</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Ninject.Web.Common</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Ninject.Web.Mvc</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>PresentationCore</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>PresentationFramework</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Activities.Presentation</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.IdentityModel</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.IdentityModel.Services</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Net.Http</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Net.Http.Formatting</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Runtime.Serialization</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Security</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ServiceModel</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ServiceModel.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.DynamicData</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Entity</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.ApplicationServices</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Data</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Data.DataSetExtensions</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Extensions</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Helpers</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Http</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Http.Tracing</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Http.WebHost</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Mvc</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Optimization</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Razor</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.WebPages</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.WebPages.Deployment</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.WebPages.Razor</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xaml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml.Linq</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Drawing</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Configuration</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Web.Services</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.EnterpriseServices</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>TuesPechkin</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>WebActivatorEx</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>WebGrease</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>WindowsBase</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>MyProject.Lib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>mscorlib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>MyProject.Web</AssemblyReference>
    </sco:Collection>
```

Im 99% sure that most of these are not used in the workflow. But if I want to run a Unit test of this flow I need to reference all these assemblies. Seems like a lot of unnecessary referencing. Can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If an activity within the workflow is using those references, then this workflow will need it as well. There is no way around that.

You could theoretically remove references one by one and try running the workflow. It will be tedious unfortunately.

A utility like ReSharper may have an automated way to clean up unused references...

Comment: I tried to remove the references bust since these references, are made in an auto generated file I wonder how long that will work.

Comment: Another way to get rid of this was to move all the workflows to a separate project but that not so easy either. Any tips on how to do that? Namespace errors etc.